# Riverpod error: Notifier not conforming to the bound of the parameter of type NotifierT

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

Im just beginning to use Riverpod, and the new Notifiers. As I understood, the `StateProvider` provider has been deprecated so I'm migrating my app to `Notifier`. But I having an error when trying to create the `NotificationProvider`. I have tried to generate the provider using `build_runner` and code generator but I got the same error in the `g.dart` file.
This is my notifier:

```
class PostAnnouncementsNotifier extends Notifier<PostAnnouncementState> {
  
  @override
   PostAnnouncementState build() {
    return state.copyWith(items: [], state: DashboardConcreteState.initial);
  }

  Future<void> fetchAnnouncements(PostAnnouncementRepository dependencies) async {
    if (state.state != DashboardConcreteState.loaded) {
      state = state.copyWith(state: DashboardConcreteState.loading);
      final response = await dependencies.fetchAnnouncements();
      _updateStateFromResponse(response);
      state = state.copyWith(
          state: state.items.isEmpty
              ? DashboardConcreteState.loading
              : DashboardConcreteState.fetchingMore);
    } else {
      state = state.copyWith(
        state: DashboardConcreteState.fetchedAllItems,
      );
    }
  }

  void _updateStateFromResponse(
      Either<AppException, List<PostItemModel>>? response) {
    response?.fold((failure) {
      state = state.copyWith(state: DashboardConcreteState.failure, items: []);
    }, (data) {
      final productList = data;
      state = state.copyWith(
        state: productList.length == data.length
            ? DashboardConcreteState.fetchedAllItems
            : DashboardConcreteState.loaded,
        items: productList,
      );
    });
  }
}
```

And this is the declaration of my provider:

```
final postAnnouncementNotifierProvider = NotifierProvider<PostAnnouncementsNotifier, DashboardConcreteState>(() { //<------------------- Here is were I'm getting the error.
  return PostAnnouncementsNotifier();
});
```

this is my state model:

```
enum DashboardConcreteState {
  initial,
  loading,
  loaded,
  failure,
  fetchingMore,
  fetchedAllItems
}

@freezed
class PostAnnouncementState with _$PostAnnouncementState {
  const factory PostAnnouncementState(
      {required List<PostItemModel> items,
      required DashboardConcreteState state,
      required int total,
      required String message}) = _PostAnnouncementState;

  const factory PostAnnouncementState.initial(
      {@Default(DashboardConcreteState.initial) DashboardConcreteState state,
      @Default([]) List<PostItemModel> items,
      @Default('0') total,
      @Default('') message}) = _InitialPostAnnouncementState;

  factory PostAnnouncementState.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$PostAnnouncementStateFromJson(json);
}
```

And finally this is the error im getting:

```
'PostAnnouncementsNotifier' doesn't conform to the bound 'Notifier<DashboardConcreteState>' of the type parameter 'NotifierT'.
Try using a type that is or is a subclass of 'Notifier<DashboardConcreteState>'.
```

Comment: build() is run *before* you have state, so I don't know what you're trying to accomplish there.

Answer (score 1):

Your notifier extends `Notifier<A>`, but your provider declared `NotifierProvider<YourNotifier, B>`

`DashboardConcreteState` => `PostAnnouncementState`

Normally you should see an error in your IDE, but there's an analyzer bug that prevents this specific scenario from showing up as a red underline in your IDE>